# Why "clear:both;" CSS doesn't work in a responsive theme?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have added the "clear:both;" css command to my responsive theme,however it doesn't work,elements wrap around my block.
Here is the HTML of my block:

```
    <div id="block-views-categories-normal-view-block-1" class="block block--views contextual-links-region block--views-categories-normal-view-block-1">
<div class="contextual-links-wrapper contextual-links-processed">
<div class="block__content">
<div class="view view-categories-normal-view view-id-categories_normal_view view-display-id-block_1 view-dom-id-4d6cdd2580eef8f5826096ea0f8157c1">
<div class="view-content">
<div class="responsive-table-wrapper">
<div class="responsive-table-scroller">
<table class="views-view-grid responsive-table-processed">
etc
```

I have tried

```
#block-views-categories-normal-view-block-1{
clear:both;
}
```

and

```
.views-view-grid {
clear:both;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Nope I am not floating,I am using a ready responsive drupal theme

Comment: See the answer below...  you need to float the parents, and then clear those.

Answer (score 1):

Need to see some more code and corresponding CSS to answer.

My guess is that you're not clearing the float of the proper element.
By putting `clear: both` on the table class, you're telling it to clear the float of some child table elements.

Unless you altered the display property of the table elements, your clear is in the incorrect place.

You need to clear the parent of your floats to fix the painting issue in the browser.